# open file with suitable program

Tags: c#, file, arrays

I want to create method whish take 2 parameters from DB

```
openFile(byte[] fileInfo,string extension)
```

then when I call this method it can choose the suitable program the open it

e.g if I call it as

```
openfile(fileInfo,"docx")
```

it automatically choose word to open byte[] and it also for excel & acces & other extensions

Comment: Are you wanting to open the file with the application that is associated in the operating system or with another application that you choose?  Also what does the fileinfo byte[] contain, the file data? Path to the file on the filesystem? Something else?

Comment: @Etienne : what the code in method :)

Comment: @MrEyes: I want to open it by application associated with OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to first save the file on the disk and then try to run it:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("foo.doc", fileInfo);
Process.Start("foo.doc");
```

Comment: so there is no way to open attachment without save it :(

Comment: It will depend on the file type and whether the program which is associated with it supports this. It is not possible to do in the general case.

Comment: Would need a namespace as well: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("foo.doc")

Answer (score 1):

You can get the windows shell to open the associated editor by starting the file as a process

```
Process.Start("example.txt");
```

This will open Notepad for example, if that is the associated editor.

You could stream your fileInfo buffer into a temporary file with the extension specified and then execute a Process.Start(yourfilenamehere) to start it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Save file with generic name and set extension.
2. Call [Process.Start Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx), system will resolve association.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said, use Process.Start() and I always do it like this to show a **open With** dialog as the system always does when the file is not associated :

```
Try
{
  Process.Start(youfile);
}
Catch (Exception e)
{
  OpenWith(youfile)//you need to implement this by yourself
}
```

EG:[Calling the Open With dialog box from your application, using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/openwith.aspx)